# How to convert ByteArrayOutputStream to Reader

Tags: java, unit-testing

Having

```
ByteArrayOutputStream b = ...;

//some code under test writes to b

 Reader result = (convert b to reader);

 IOUtils.contentEqualsIgnoreEOL(expected, result);
```

How to convert a `ByteArrayOutputStream` to a `Reader`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can try

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = 
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()));
```

a simpler solution would be to check the contents of the buffer.

```
assertEquals(expected, baos.toString().trim());
```

Comment: This will work, but this way you copy all the data. Isn't there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Not unless you implement your own. If you were worried about efficiency, you might use a StringBuilder instead to avoid the encoding/decoding which can take much longer (or something wrapping it)  As its for unit testing correctness is more important than  efficiency.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux - not if you start with a `ByteArrayInputStream`.  And for the OP's use-case, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Well I need any `OutputStream` implementation.. that needs to be compared with some contents from a file..

Comment: In that case I would use ByteArrayOutputStream and toString() it when finished.